# is there a better way to make a composite key and a partial unique constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, unique-constraint

I have the following create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `unique_column` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `other_column` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`unique_column`),
  KEY `composite` (`unique_column`, `other_column`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Usual select includes
`select * from Foo where unique_column=x` and `select * from Foo where unique_column in (x_arr) and other_column in (y_arr)` and hence the two keys.

Here I create two separate keys for the unique constraint and the composite key. I have a feeling that there is a better way of doing this that I don't know of, such that only one key is created in terms of space-efficiency but the unique constraint is also satisfied.

The reason I have this feeling is that, if there is no unique constraint the second composite key also accounts for the first select and the first key is not needed.

Explain Tests:

explain select * from Foo where `unique_column` = 1;
[image]

explain select * from Foo where `unique_column` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) and `other_column` in (1,2);
[image]

Comment: Are there really only 3 columns in the real table?  If you had a 4th column, your second Explain would change.

Comment: In deed if I added a fourth column the select shows it will not use any keys. Could you explain why this is the case? And if there is a way to index the select?

Comment: I have heard of when the dataset is small sometimes MySQL will not use the keys but not really sure if this is the case. I will try to find a way to create a large enough data and see what happens.

Comment: I created a larger set and indeed only the "unique" key is used. Even if I remove the unique constraint it seems only the single key is used. So indeed it seems the second composite key is abundant Why is this the case though?

Comment: Long story -- involving multiple INs, the unique index being smaller than the composite, etc.  Have you tried my change to the PK?

Comment: Tried and it shows PRIMARY and composite as possible keys but only PRIMARY is used. In my real table to be created the ID is also going to be used for select so maybe there isn't a different which is primary and which is unique key.

Comment: So if there are multiple INs and one key is a subset of another composite key, the smaller single key will always be used, am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `id` and promote the UNIQUE to be the PK.

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`unique_column`),
KEY `composite` (`unique_column`, `other_column`)
```

-->

```
PRIMARY KEY (`unique_column`)
```

There is essentially no advantage in adding the composite key.  Since `unique_column` is Unique, there is only one row with a given value.  Any test on `other_column` is simple enough.

Two `IN` clauses in the WHERE --

First note that if there is only one item in the `IN`, the Optimizer turns it into `=`, which is easier to optimize.  Please say whether that is your case, and for which column -- it may make a difference.

What version of MySQL are you using?

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` for any examples you try.

Some other vendors have a way of specifying extra columns on the end of UNIQUE without taking part in the uniqueness constraint.  MySQL does not have such syntax.

Comment: I have added the explain select results. I am using version 5.7.3 and yes the in statements include an array of values (I tried to simplify the usage at the beginning when asking this question but realized the difference so I edited to include the more complicated original usage).

Comment: @cr001 - Simpler is better, except when it leads the Optimizer to do something different.  Another possible hiccup is if `*` includes a `TEXT` column.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Fortunately TEXT columns aren't going to be included, all strings are going to be stored as varchar(255). However the in statement might also be used as "order by" statement, which I have also tested and had the same results as IN. If you could double assure to me that the composite key will never be used with two "INs" or "IN + order by" I will accept the answer.

Comment: @cr001 - There are probably cases where _both columns_ of the composite key will be used.  But, if the `PRIMARY KEY` is `(unique_column)`, then many such cases will be _faster_.  (But probably not all cases.)  Suggest you find the likely queries and list them; I can comment about them specifically.  (And you can test them.)